# Why does git-prompt.sh indicate my branches have diverged?

Tags: git, bash, shell, github

I recently switched from [git-aware-prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt) to git's [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) because I like the added features. However, after setting `GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"` in my bash profile, every repo I'm using with GitHub indicates a divergence with '<>', instead of the expected '='.

I don't understand this because `git status` shows 
`Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit, working tree clean` 
and `git pull` reads `Already up-to-date`. Am I missing something about divergence, or is git-prompt.sh not behaving properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the *exact* (count any spaces and/or tab characters) text output from `git rev-list --count --left-right @{upstream}...HEAD`? Does this match exactly with the version of `git-prompt.sh` you have? (See line 196 in particular. Cut-and-paste may have expanded a tab into some number of spaces.) The prompt-setter depends on the exact output format.

Comment: Weirdly enough I just came here to close the issue. I was putzing around `/usr/local/etc` and I discovered that Homebrew had already installed git-prompt.sh into a directory called `bash_completion.d`. When I sourced this file instead of the one I downloaded (located in my home-folder or some such) it worked perfectly. I'm pretty confused, but glad it worked out. Probably a cut and paste error, like you said. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @torek just did what you said because I was curious. Looks like the working copy has a two space tab between the two zeros, just like the output of the command you sent. I'll watch out for that next time, thanks again.

Comment: @torek Interestingly, a friend of mine is having a similar problem, except his prompt shows `(master *+)` even when he's not in a git repo. I've been looking over the differences between his and mine, and based on what you said I think it might have something to do with the way Sublime converts spaces to tabs. Is there an easier way to paste the raw git-prompt.sh into his /usr/local/bin/bash_completion.d directory? Would `curl https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh -o /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh` work?

Comment: Certainly anything that whacks on tabs-vs-spaces can cause this, including editors that do that. The fix I would prefer is to make the script itself less sensitive to the precise form of whitespace, but that requires whoever maintains the script to fix it. I don't normally run a command-line `curl` but that does look likely to work (though in case of network issues I'd save the result to a temp file, and then move the temp file in place locally only once the result is ready to go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got access to my friend's machine, and tried curling the raw script into the correct directory: `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh -o /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh`. It worked! But no one should do this until they're positive that
a. `git` is installed via Homebrew (you can verify this; if `which git` returns `/usr/local/bin/git` and you didn't make that symlink yourself, you're all set.
b. No `git` links are broken (`brew unlink git` then `brew link git` ought to fix any problems)

Based on @torek's expertise, I've come to the conclusion that Sublime 3 might have been converting tabs to spaces and breaking the script. The solution is not to open `git-prompt.sh` in any text editor, but instead curl it directly into the above directory. This way one can be sure that it is uncorrupted and works as advertised.

Comment: I should mention it's entirely possible that Sublime had nothing to do with it. My friend's problem was that after we copied and pasted (via Sublime) the script into his bash_completion folder, his home directory showed master branch and both staged and unstaged changes. But when I finally got access to his machine, I found a git repo initialized in his home folder! But I had some weird behavior from mine at first, too, so I think the above solution is a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my recent experience:

I believe that it's a tabs vs spaces issue as mentioned above. If you are having this problem, look for this section in `git-prompt.sh`:

```sh
203     # calculate the result
204     if [[ -z "$verbose" ]]; then
205         case "$count" in
206         "") # no upstream
207             p="" ;;
208         "0  0") # equal to upstream
209             p="=" ;;
210         "0  "*) # ahead of upstream
211             p=">" ;;
212         *"  0") # behind upstream
213             p="<" ;;
214         *)        # diverged from upstream
215             p="<>" ;;
216         esac
217     else
218         case "$count" in
219         "") # no upstream
220             p="" ;;
221         "0  0") # equal to upstream
222             p=" u=" ;;
223         "0  "*) # ahead of upstream
224             p=" u+${count#0    }" ;;
225         *"  0") # behind upstream
226             p=" u-${count%    0}" ;;
227         *)        # diverged from upstream
228             p=" u+${count#*    }-${count%    *}" ;;
229         esac
230         if [[ -n "$count" && -n "$name" ]]; then
231             __git_ps1_upstream_name=$(git rev-parse \
232                 --abbrev-ref "$upstream" 2>/dev/null)
233             if [ $pcmode = yes ] && [ $ps1_expanded = yes ]; then
234                 p="$p \${__git_ps1_upstream_name}"
235             else
236                 p="$p ${__git_ps1_upstream_name}"
237                 # not needed anymore; keep user's
238                 # environment clean
239                 unset __git_ps1_upstream_name
240             fi
241         fi
242     fi
243
244 }
```

and ensure that the strings in the cases containing "0" that the whitespaces are *tabs* (unless your shell is expanding them somehow, in which case the opposite will be true I guess)